# Coldfusion leftside menu takes more time to render

Tags: coldfusion

In CF application, the data in left side menu is dynamically displaying using database tables, from XML's & coldfusion structures. To read data from tables,xmls,structures multiple components are using in CFcode as it takes 30 seconds of time to display data in left side menu. In debugging information it shows 2seconds of time is the Total Time For Execution for all components loading and all function calls, but menu options renders after 25 seconds only, In console the time taken for Ajax http call shows as 25 seconds to loading data, How Can I reduce the time to render menu data. For the first time only this issue occurs, from the second time It loads with in 8 seconds due to coldfusion caching, Can I put these cf components in Cache after login into application, I tried to put cf components in session scope It does not reduce the time. Please suggest.

Comment: Without seeing any code, it's hard to help you.

Comment: Hi Rose, Thanks for the update, The CFM page which holds/ shows the menu data, uses "ShowCriteria" function, In this function It creates multiple component objects using "createObject",these r approximately 10 components and few of these components extends other components and so on...My doubt is " loading all these hierarchical components and execution of the functions inside these components takes more time to get final menu content.

Comment: You can try isolating all those components to a different page and then analyse the rendering/loading time.

Comment: Hi Anit, How can I put all these components in logged in user session cfcache when user logs in APP.

Comment: We need to see actual code, not your description of the code.